# Is this conditional probability formula always true?

Tags: probability, statistics

Are the following equations always true for conditional probabilities?Are there any instances when we can not interchange these equations?

$P(A|B^c) = P(A ∩ B^c) / P(B^c) = P(B^c ∩A)/(1-P(B)) = (P(A) - P(B∩A))/(1-P(B))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use them.

They only use the definition of compliments and identities, which are always valid.